# How to print different dataframes based of user input? Rmarkdown/Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to have a user select a data frame and then have it be rendered as a table.

Here is the code I have.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "2/24/2022"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---


```{r}


selectInput(inputId = "dataset",label = "Choose Data Frame", choices = c(mtcars, iris, cars))

renderTable({
    dataset <- get(input$dataset, choices = c(mtcars, iris, cars))
 })



```
````

Although for some reason the inputs are the column names of each dataset.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We may need `choices` as  a vector of object names as string and then use `get` (assuming these objects are already created in the global env)

```
selectInput(inputId = "dataset",label = "Choose Data Frame",
    choices = c("mtcars", "iris", "cars"))

renderTable({
  dataset <- get(input$dataset)
})
```

-output

[image]